# Why does Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional") errors when appengine is deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus, google-cloud-sql

I have created an appengine which runs fine and returns records from my Google cloud SQL db in debug mode. When I deploy the appegine and run the endpoint it errors. And the error I get in the appengine log is:

Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType".

Here is a list or the jars in war\WEB-INF\lib directory:

- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6
- appengine-api-labs
- appengine-endpoints
- appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.6
- asm-4.0
- com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0
- com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950
- datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3
- datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3
- datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2
- datanucleus-core-3.1.3
- eclipselink
- eclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
- gcm-server
- geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0
- javax.activation_1.1.0.v201108011116
- javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615
- javax.persistence_2.0.4.v201112161009
- javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648
- javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200
- jdo-api-3.0.1
- json_simple-1.1
- jsr107cache-1.1
- jta-1.1
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider></provider>
        <class>com.example.myapp.Class1</class>
        <class>com.example.myapp.Class2</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://something.com:someproj:someapp/somedb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Using:
cloud sql
JPA
Datanucleous v2
SDK 1.7.6
Jre7

As it works fine in debug mode I dont understand what the problem might be as I am new to appengine. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your mind up which JPA provider you're using ... for Cloud SQL (not AppEngine, so you don't need "*datanucleus-appengine*", nor do you need "*datanucleus-api-jdo*" either FWIW). You have DataNucleus JPA (version 3 actually, but omitting *datanucleus-rdbms* jar for some reason, yet CloudSQL needs it), and you have EclipseLink also. You then don't set the persistence provider in *persistence.xml* so leave it all to chance which one it tries to give you ... and it tries DataNucleus JPA but you haven't included the *datanucleus-rdbms* jar so you can't persist to an RDBMS without that.

Comment: Thanks DataNucleus for your help. I have made the changes you have suggested. When I run the appengine in debug mode it now errors with the  following: "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Required table missing : \"`MYTABLE`\" in Catalog \"\" Schema \"\". DataNucleus requires this table to perform its persistence operations. Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable \"datanucleus.autoCreateTables\"". What do I need to do to resolve this? I had a simular error and I used @Table annotation in the entity class , but this is not working now.

Comment: it tells you what to do, add that persistence property